# ckediter equiped textbox restricting number of characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

While there are a couple of older questions that touch on this topic, they are not dealing with webforms, which is where I am working and the code does not seem to be kicking in.

In a ASP.NET web forms application that needs to collect rtf data, I have enabled several fields with ckeditor to allow rtf input (stored as html). On some of these fields I need a means to limit input.

element to be restricted in the form/table:

```aspx
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelResponseA" runat="server">Response A</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ResponseA" Columns="50" Rows="2" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            runat="server" CssClass="ckeditor"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
            Text="* Response A Required" ControlToValidate="ResponseA" 
            SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

javascript code block for the restriction of characters:

```aspx
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {            
        $("[id$=ResponseA]").on('key',function(event){
            var deleteKey = 46;
            var backspaceKey = 8;
            var keyCode = event.data.keyCode;
            if (keyCode === deleteKey || keyCode === backspaceKey)
                return true;
            else
            {
                var textLimit = 50;
                var str = $("[id$=ResponseA]").getData();
                if (str.length >= textLimit)
                    return false;
            }
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [editor "key" event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key) and check the editor's body text length.

If your editor's textarea is named `ResponseA`:

```
var textLimit = 50;

CKEDITOR.instances.ResponseA.on('key', function (evt) {
    if (CKEDITOR.instances.ResponseA.document.getBody().getText().length > textLimit) evt.cancel();
});
```

You can expand this bare bones example further to fit your needs.

Comment: Atzmon, unfortunately that does not work, still accepting characters well in excess of 50.

Comment: I tested this with the [vanilla ckeditor getting started sample](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation) and it works as expected. If you post more of your code and how ckeditor is instantiated, maybe we can see the difference and offer a more precise function that fits better to your specific scenario.